# GETting plain content in presence of JAX-RS

Tags: rest, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I have a project which is basically an Apache Wicket web app, but it also has 3 REST services. I'd like to keep these two different technologies together in one application, as they share quite a lot of classes. Also, I'd like them to share the same JPA instance, as they operate on the same database.

The problem I'm facing is that, as soon as any JAX-RS path is specified, all URLs sent to the application appear to be handled by JAX-RS, even if the REST paths specified don't justify this. Concretely:

```
@PATH("service")
public class ServiceClassA
@PATH("s1")
public String someMethod...

@PATH("service")
public class ServiceClassB
...
```

Please note that thereby all defined services have a URI starting "MyAppName/service/...".

The Wicket classes are unaffected by this, as probably the Wicket filter runs before JAX-RS has a chance to grab the URL. But plain resources like css files get in the hands of JAX-RS, resulting in a

```
No root resource matching request path browser/xxx.css has been found, Relative Path: /browser/xxx.css.
```

The JAX-RS endpoints contain, in addition to those for the service methods shown above, a general one:

```
REST Application: http://localhost:8080/MyAppName/ -> org.apache.openejb.server.rest.InternalApplication
```

As soon as I remove all @PATH annotations, my css is served normally. So I suspect that the endpoint just shown is automatically generated and causes any URI of my app to be handled by the REST framework, even if no path was defined for it. So what I basically need is to tell JAX-RS to ignore

- either all URIs not starting with "MyAppName/service",
- or all URIs starting with "MyAppName/browser",
- or to redirect all URIs it can't handle to the standard Web Server mechanism.

I experimented and googled for possible configuration options quite a lot, but still I didn't find anything suitable for such a simple requirement. I'd appreciate any hints.

BTW, my web.xml is plain vanilla. It contains the wicket filter, mapped to /*, and nothing else, in particular no filtering or servlet for JAX-RS. The server is TomEE-plus 1.6.0.2, and the JAX-RS libraries are the ones shipped with TomEE.

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS is a servlet so without binding it to a sub context of your app it conflicts with resources. You can provide an `Application` with `@Application("subcontext")`.

Note: TomEE supports exclusion of some static resources but the configuration is explicit in openejb-jar (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-728) so first solution is easier.

Comment: I couldn't find a place where to put an Application annotation. But [link]http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/rest-example-with-application/README.html put my on the right track, using an explicit configuration class with an ApplicationPath annotation.